# Open shift clean up pods with completed status

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

We clean up pods with completed status manually. Is there a way to automate cleaning up pods that have completed status?

Comment: Not easy to implement with few simple kubectl commands, since `Completed` is a kubectl  output status not a pod status phase. May need to write your own shell scripts to do this.

Comment: By the way, `kubectl delete po --field-selector status.phase=Succeeded -A` may help you delete `Succeeded` phase pods.

Answer (score 0):

Extending Yuwei's answer:

There is no built-in option to automate such "garbage collection", that's why there is a workaround to make a simple script of `kubectl` command by using `timeout` command. [Here](https://linuxize.com/post/timeout-command-in-linux/#how-to-use-the-timeout-command) you can find the article on How to use Timeout command.

So it will be something like this:

```
timeout -s9 300m kubectl delete pod --field-selector status.phase=Succeeded -A
```

or

```
timeout -s9 300m kubectl delete job &lt;job-name&gt;
```